# A generalization of the Hermite polynomial: is there a name for this class of polynomials in the literature?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, terminology, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

An explicit expression for the `probabilist's' Hermite polynomial is given by $$\sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^r\frac{n!}{2^r(n-2r)!r!}x^{n-2r}.$$ In playing around with some combinatorics, I came across the following variant $$\sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor n/k\rfloor}(-1)^r\frac{n!}{(k!)^r(n-kr)!r!}x^{n-kr}.$$
Do these polynomials belong to any known or standard class of (orthogonal) polynomials? Is there anything known about them?

Comment: Perhaps computing the generating function you will conclude that is a Sheffer sequence? Most likely an Appell sequence too? It seems to me that the generating function has to be $e^{xt-t^k/k!}$ cause essentially you are counting set partitions in blocks of size $k$ and $1.$

Comment: @Phicar: thank you for you comment, I will look into this. Do you have any idea on how to show the generating function is indeed $e^{xt-t^k/k!}$? This polynomial came up as counting set partitions in blocks of $1$ and $k$, indeed.

Comment: I will use the language of combinatorial species, in the sense that exponential is a sequence and so you are taking sequences of size 1 and k and you divide by the factorial to take out the order of each individual sequence. Probably you should take a look at the generating function of Bell numbers.

Comment: @Phicar Thanks again, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i went over some literature, and you can express your polynomials as
$$_SH_n^{(k)}(x,y)=\sum _{r=0}^{n/k}\frac{n!y^rx^{n-rk}}{r!(n-rk)!},$$ by doing $y=\frac{(-1)}{k!}.$

This polynomials are called Gould Hopper. For example check the paper(Table I, first row):

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.09139.pdf